# How to make NFT data fetching tools on EVM blockchain like the Moralis?

Tags: nft, evm, moralis

I am going to make own NFT fetching tools like the Moralis NFT apis.
What we need to develop that apis?

Comment: The question is too broad. Try focusing in a single api then start building on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

Developer advocate from [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here.

TL, DR: You need to index the data by yourself, which requires re-executing many historical transactions.

Essentially all NFT ownership data and Metadata are available on the blockchain itself. Theoretically, you can query every NFT smart contract to get all the owners' addresses.

This may be useful to bootstrap a database for your NFT API but it is not feasible to maintain a database with this approach. You don't want to re-scan the whole blockchain whenever a block is updated.

A more common approach is monitoring the block execution logs:

1. Starting from the contract's deployment date, replay all blocks until now.
2. Index every transaction and do the necessary data transformation to keep a record of the owners and transaction data.
3. Keep the program running and keep the database updated

The benefit of this is:

1. Transaction historical data is available
2. Database for API is updated in realtime
3. You only need to run it once for all NFTs

The limitation of this is:

1. You need to have an archive node for historical data

Our platform [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) offers archive Ethereum node at a cost. Our [indexing service](https://chainstack.com/subgraphs/) is on Beta stage right now, but you can signup for EA.

Hope that helps.